# API with Node & Express gives back old cached response until newer is retrieved

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I cannot find how to prevent this behavior. I have a very simple Express API that works well and gives the intended response. It´s connected to a database storing press articles.

The problem comes when I request article with id 1. It shows up. Then I try to request article with id number 2, and instead I am getting the cached response of the previous article. This goes on for as long as it takes for the database to actually deliver the article 2.

This is what I have:

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var response;

var dbConfig = {
    //connection details
};

function getArt(an) {

    var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);

    conn.connect().then(function() {
            var req = new sql.Request(conn);
            req.query(/* query to the DB */).then(function(recordset) {
                    response = recordset;
                    conn.close();
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    response = err;
                    conn.close();
                });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            response = err;
            conn.close();
        })

    return response;
}

var app = express();

app.get('/sourcedeletion/api/v2.0/article/:an', function(req, res) {
    res.send(getArt(req.params.an.toString()));
});

app.listen(3000);
```

What part am I missing, that could help me to get the real response on every request, rather than the previous cached one until the new one arrives from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a global variable `response` that is not enclosed in the scope of the request. This is prone to error! `getArt` returns the value of the global variable `response` without waiting for the promise to execute, so it returns an old value. You should do:

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const dbConfig = {
    //connection details
};

const getArt = (an) => {
    const conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);
    return conn.connect()
      .then(() => {
        const req = new sql.Request(conn);
        return req.query(/* query to the DB */)
      })
      .catch(err => err)
      .then(response => {
        conn.close();
        return response;
      });
  });
};

const app = express();

app.get('/sourcedeletion/api/v2.0/article/:an', (req, res) => {
  getArt(req.params.an.toString())
    .then(response => {
      res.send(response);
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thanks. Not only because it worked, but also because of the extra ES6 changes you made, so I was able to learn a couple of new things too.

Comment: I like to always return promises, else it's too easy to forget to wait for them. For instance you're not returning `req.query`. And I try to never use global variables for things that don't make sense out of the context of a given request. Too easy to mix them up!

Answer (score 1):

```
con.connection()
```

.. is an async call, so before the new response is set, the function returns what ever was there before.

If you want to make sure that the function waits for the connection to finish before returning a value try to change to the following:

```
return conn.connect().then(function() {
  var req = new sql.Request(conn);
  return req.query(/* query to the DB */).then(function(recordset) {
    response = recordset;
    return response;
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    response = err;
    return response;
  });
})
```